# Unable to copy file from Docker container to host

Tags: docker, copy, containers

```
$ docker cp maven-container_:xxxx.war /home/wissem/Documents/docker-stage/wildfly-configured/target/
```

Error response from daemon: lstat

> /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/afbdc7f4ce3165fb2e6c34929841b9fa911de1978887dd5b9b0804e4f624af2d
>   /xxxx.war: no such file or directory
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Comment: You need to copy from a running instance and not an image. So I assume `maven-container_` is a name of the container your had launched and not a image. Also use complete path after `:`, `docker cp maven-container_:/path/inside/container/xxxx.war /home/wissem/Documents/docker-stage/wildfly-configured/target/`

Comment: SOLVED : it was my path : docker cp maven-container_:/opt/maven/targe/xxxx.war  ....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to copy from a running instance and not an image. So I assume `maven-container_` is a name of the container your had launched and not a image. Also use complete path after `:`,

```
docker cp maven-container_:/path/inside/container/xxxx.war /home/wissem/Documents/docker-stage/wildfly-configured/targe‌​t/
```

Comment: Thsnk. Helped me figure out the problem.

Comment: doesn't need to be running

Comment: to copy from an image without running it - create a container with a name.  docker create my_image_tag --name my_cont_name; docker cp my_cont_name:/path/file /home/...

Comment: Thanks, i was trying to copy out after my test container had exited after finishing tests.  I guess the test image is not the same as the instance of `docker run`, which was a fork of the container image that is lost when it's done?

Answer (score 10):

I got this error when trying to copy a file under the root folder (seems related to @uthomas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56911131/2016436)).

```
$ docker cp dreamy_brown:/root/myfile.txt ~
Error: No such container:path: dreamy_brown:/root/myfile.txt
```

Solution: From within the container I first moved the file to the `/tmp` folder:

```
$ mv /root/myfile.txt /tmp
```

and then I was able to copy it to the host:

```
$ docker cp dreamy_brown:/tmp/myfile.txt ~
```

Comment: For anyone else in "Solution" step you have to be inside the container first. I was running inside compose: `$docker-compose exec CONTAINER_NAME bash`. That brought me to `/root/` where I could then move/copy files to tmp as explained.

Answer (score 6):

For me it didn't work because of permissions. The file I was trying to copy was owned by postgres user, while the default user seems to be root.

Comment: Weird since root user should have access to everything. I tried the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64304936/3003133) by @asherbret to first move them to `/tmp` but that is not helping. Plus, the files I am looking at are owned by root, have permissions `-rw-r--r--.`, and are not links. Unless them being root is the problem because the container's default user in my case is something else... Nope, `whoami` says root.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't copy because I was using wildcards.

Didn't work:

```
docker cp af1f3010481a:/tmp/mydir/* .
```

Worked:

```
docker cp af1f3010481a:/tmp/mydir/myfile.txt .
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I found that I just need to restart the mysql container.